# Adding Image to wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add an `Image` dynamically to the wpf application.

What I have tried :

```
            Image img = new Image();
            img.Height = 100;
            img.Width = 100;
            img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            Thickness th = new Thickness(100, 100, 0, 0);
            img.Margin = th;

            string strUri2 = String.Format(@"pack://application:,,,/MyFirstWPF;component/Images/tt.jpg");
            img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(strUri2));
```

I know, the image won't display unless I add it to the Content.

```
this.Content=img;
```

but with this the existing controls(shapes) on the app are lost.

Now, my question is how to add the image to the content without losing existing controls from the app.

Comment: you should add it to your controls container (parent)

Comment: What is `this` in `this.Content`?

Comment: so what is you first child in visual tree (grid, stackpanel,...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are going to load and show an image dynamically, you still need to think about the layout of your application. I would suggest to add an (initially empty) Image control in XAML (for example in a Grid), and later set the `Source` property of this control in code.

```
<Grid>
    ... other controls ...
    <Image Name="img" Grid.Row="..." Grid.Column="..."
           Width="100" Height="100" Margin="100,100,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

Set `Source` in code:

```
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyFirstWPF;component/Images/tt.jpg");     
img.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

Answer (score 1):

by default the window content is a grid so try

```
(this.Content as Grid).Children.Add(img);
```