# image.Source property does not setted

Tags: c#, wpf, image, uri

i have the below code in c# (WPF):

```
            Image image = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
        BitmapImage bitmapImage= new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/WorkFlow/1.png", UriKind.Relative));
        image.Source = bitmapImage;
```

in the above code, the bitmap image loaded perfectly but when it is setted to be the source of Imagecontrol, the source will remain null and does not get that bitmapiamge.
how can i solve that?

Comment: Have you added your Image control (`Image image = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();`) to your form/grid? Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12025922/6170142) for further explanation about it.

Comment: yes, i have added the image with a text to a stackpanel and set it to the content of a tree view item. but it shows the text only and image fails but bitmap image is loaded correctly but not setted to the source of image.

Comment: "the source will remain null" can't be true, because of the assignment `image.Source = bitmapImage;`. You probably mean that the image isn't visible. Check if your relative path is valid at runtime. Better set the image file's Build Action to Resource and load it by a Resource File Pack URI, i.e. `new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/WorkFlow/1.png")`.

Comment: Thanks very much. it worked very nice.!!!!